# Why is H2oFrame ignoring my input column types?

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to specify the column types going into my H2o.Frame. I have tried this several different ways and in every case. Unit tests are below. They all fail except the last two but those last two only work because I have changed 99.0 to 99.9. Why can't I tell it that 99.0 is still a float and not an int?

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
import h2o

class TestInputtingTypes(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        h2o.init()

    def test_h2o_1(self):
        data =[(1,'one', 9),(9,'two',3), (8,'three', 99.0)]
        given_types = {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'real'}
        frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_types=given_types)
        actual_types = frame.types

        self.assertDictEqual(given_types, actual_types)

    def test_h2o_2(self):
        data =[(1,'one', 9),(9,'two',3), (8,'three', 99.0)]
        given_types = {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'real'}
        names = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
        frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_types=given_types, column_names=names)
        actual_types = frame.types

        self.assertDictEqual(given_types, actual_types)

    def test_h2o_3(self):
        data =[{'C1': 1, 'C2': 'one',   'C3': 9},
               {'C1': 9, 'C2': 'two',   'C3': 3},
               {'C1': 8, 'C2': 'three', 'C3': 99.0}]

        given_types = {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'real'}
        names = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
        frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_types=given_types, column_names=names)
        actual_types = frame.types

        self.assertDictEqual(given_types, actual_types)

    def test_h2o_4(self):
        data =[{'C1': 1, 'C2': 'one',   'C3': 9},
               {'C1': 9, 'C2': 'two',   'C3': 3},
               {'C1': 8, 'C2': 'three', 'C3': 99.0}]

        given_types = {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'real'}
        given_types_input = {'C1': 'numeric', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'float'}
        names = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
        frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_types=given_types_input, column_names=names)
        actual_types = frame.types

        self.assertDictEqual(given_types, actual_types)

    def test_h2o_5(self):
        data =[(1,'one', 9),(9,'two',3), (8,'three', 99.0)]
        given_types = ['int', 'string', 'real']
        names = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
        frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_types=given_types, column_names=names)
        actual_types = frame.types

        self.assertDictEqual(given_types, actual_types)

    def test_h2o_6_this_one_passes_because_has_nonzero_decimals(self):
        data =[(1,'one', 9),(9,'two',3), (8,'three', 99.9)]
        given_types = {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'real'}
        given_types_input = ['int', 'string', 'real']
        names = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
        frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_types=given_types_input, column_names=names)
        actual_types = frame.types

        self.assertDictEqual(given_types, actual_types)

    def test_h2o_7_this_one_passes_because_has_nonzero_decimals(self):
        data =[(1,'one', 9),(9,'two',3), (8,'three', 99.9)]
        given_types = {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'real'}
        names = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
        frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data)
        actual_types = frame.types

        self.assertDictEqual(given_types, actual_types)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `int` isn't an option you can pass to the h2o `col_types` parameter, you need to pass `numeric`.

If you pass `numeric` for your real and int values,  that should solve your problem - though the integers will be converted to floats. For 
 H2O integers are used so they can be mapped to categorical (using `.asfactor()`)

In H2O the following types are allowed

“unknown” - this will force the column to be parsed as all NA

“uuid” - the values in the column must be true UUID or will be parsed as NA

“string” - force the column to be parsed as a string

“numeric” - force the column to be parsed as numeric. H2O will handle the compression of the numeric data in the optimal manner.

“enum” - force the column to be parsed as a categorical column.

“time” - force the column to be parsed as a time column. H2O will attempt to parse the following list of date time formats: (date) “yyyy-MM-dd”, “yyyy MM dd”, “dd-MMM-yy”, “dd MMM yy”, (time) “HH:mm:ss”, “HH:mm:ss:SSS”, “HH:mm:ss:SSSnnnnnn”, “HH.mm.ss” “HH.mm.ss.SSS”, “HH.mm.ss.SSSnnnnnn”. Times can also contain “AM” or “PM”.

you can see more details in the docs: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=import_file#h2o.import_file

Comment: Passing in "numeric" instead of "real" will not fix the problem.  If you pass in "numeric" in a column that can be converted to integers like [9,3,99.0], then `frame.types` will still show "int" as the type.

Answer (score 2):

In H2O, data storage is optimized by H2O, so if you have a column that can be stored with fewer bytes (such as an "int"), then H2O will store it that way, even if you try to force it to use the "real" (or float) type.

For specifying column types, H2O has it's own vocabulary for describing the types (detailed in Lauren's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088244/5451344)), but you'll see that when you specify "numeric" for that third column, it will end up as an int.

```
data =[(1,'one', 9),(9,'two',3), (8,'three', 99.0)]
given_types = {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'numeric'}
frame = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_types=given_types)
actual_types = frame.types
```

Results in:

```
In [39]: actual_types
Out[39]: {u'C1': u'int', u'C2': u'string', u'C3': u'int'}

In [40]: given_types
Out[40]: {'C1': 'int', 'C2': 'string', 'C3': 'numeric'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use the `h2o.`[`import_file`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=import_file#h2o.import_file)`()` after saving the file to csv with the argument `col_types` passed instead of `h2o.H2OFrame()`. That solved my problem.